# Secure only some routes with express-jwt

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I have "public" routes, and "API" routes which should be authenticated by `express-jwt`.

```
// define public routes in a router
const routerPublic = express.Router();
routerPublic.route("/login", (req, res) => /* whatever */);
routerPublic.route("/about-us", (req, res) => /* whatever */);
routerPublic.route("/foo/bar/baz", (req, res) => /* whatever */);

// define API routes in a router
const routerApi = express.Router();
routerApi.route("/api/v1/foo", (req, res) => /* whatever */);
routerApi.route("/api/v1/bar", (req, res) => /* whatever */);

// add routers to express app
app.use(routerPublic);                                 // (1)
app.use(routerApi, jwt({ secret: "secret" }));         // (2)
```

So I populate two `express.Router` instances - one with unsecured routes, and the other with secured routes. Then I load those routers into the express app, and only the secured routes should undergo authentication.

But the order is important. If line (1) comes before (2) then it works as expected. But if (2) comes before (1) then everything undergoes authentication, both secure and insecure routes.

So there is a race condition and I don't understand it.

Comment: did you try to use this?
 `app.use("/api/v1/", jwt({ secret: "secret" })); `

Comment: @ShayMoshe No because that doesn't work in my design. All the examples show that, but that's the kind of code you can write if everything is in one file, and there is no design to speak of. When there is separation, then more fine-grained control is needed as I've shown, but it doesn't seem to work that way :(

Comment: I think I know what can help you, your using the new express route, can you try something like this: `routerApi.use(jwt({ secret: "secret" }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting it as an answer in order to help others,

Your using the new express route, can you try something like this:

```
routerApi.use(jwt({ secret: "secret" }))
```

Comment: I forgot that the router is itself a mini app, so it can also take middleware! Thanks!